# Refreshing Heroku Page Only Shows API Information, Not Page Content

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, heroku

I deployed a PERN stack app to heroku. It is working fine, but when I refresh the page when at this url - https://earth-nights.herokuapp.com/episode/1 - I no longer see the page content, just the API information:

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Earth Nights #1",
"date_of_show": "April 24, 2020",
"teaser": "Welcome to the first Earth Nights playlist!",
"card_image": "https://cdn.technologynetworks.com/tn/images/thumbs/jpeg/640_360/the-psychedelic-revolution-in-psychiatry-333007.jpg"
}
```

Here is a link to the live app, if that helps: https://earth-nights.herokuapp.com/
When you navigate to the next page by clicking on the card on the homepage, it should load the content, but then refreshing that page displays the API info only.

Any idea as to why this could be happening?

Comment: The developer console shows a 304 code when I refresh. This suggests that your app is misbehaving - not working fine. It could be an issue specific to the Heroku platform, so start with going through the logs that Heroku generates and provides to you.

Comment: My problem is solved! I didn't realize that it was a problem to use the same routes for my server and client sides, and that was what was causing the page reload to display the JSON data instead of the actual content of the page. So I just changed my server-side routes to include '/api' before the actual name of the route, and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

as @jon said, add '/api' to the api call routes on your front-end and the corresponding routes on your server.

from

```
 '/q/:id'
```

to

```
'/api/q/:id'
```